# Getting a type error when writing a function: Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.(2345)

Tags: typescript, function, undefined

I'm writing a function that extracts the last character of a string, then converts it to number. However, *TypeScript* returns an error about the string possibly being `undefined`. But how could that be possible, given that I had predefined the type?

```js
type DogName = "dog1" | "dog2" | "dog3"

const parseDogNumber = (dogName: DogName): number => {
    const dogNumber = dogName.at(-1) // this returns a string
    const asInt = parseInt(dogNumber) // this returns a number
//                           ^^^^^
// Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
//   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.(2345)
     

    return asInt
}
```

One way I can circumvent the error is by explicitly specifying `as string` for the type of `dogNumber`:

```js
const parseDogNumber2 = (dogName: DogName): number => {
    const dogNumber = dogName.at(-1) as string 
    const asInt = parseInt(dogNumber) // this returns a number
    return asInt
}
```

But I still don't understand *why* I am getting the error in the first place, even though I typed `DogName` specifically, leaving no room for `undefined`.

---

[TS playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/C4TwDgpgBAIg9gcwHIEMC20C8UBEATRARhygB9cCEAmE8-RAZhwChmBjOAOwGdgowUAJ24R4yAK5oARhEFRsACkqoMALliIVEAJTrOkmXMwA%20KAG9mUK1A48%20yg7PlRl6CADoUwBQFpC2qAB6QKhgAAsAS24oQQhgcUEeKBQoXkEIzgRLa1teZO4ASU4%20bAFhCCLvB2lZAODQyOjY%20MTolP0awWyrZoTOfMrmAF9WXL4ykTEkR0EqZyVNN3Upt10oDsN5UwtrGy486s3sVwxPbz8AlGi0jIQobr27AeLnCYrihYlOupDwqJi4n02usZg9eolnsBhkA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when you use `String.prototype.at`, TypeScript uses built in type of `at` method:

```js
String.at(index: number): string | undefined
```

It means that if even you are 100% sure that It should return `string`, TS still think that it is `string | undefined`.

Comment: Then what should you do when such a scenario occurs @captain-yossarianfromUkraine